# A neighborhood basis for $x\in\Pi_{\lambda\in\Lambda} S_\lambda$. ("Introduction to Set Theory and Topology" (in Japanese) by Kazuo Matsuzaka.)

Tags: general-topology

I am reading "Introduction to Set Theory and Topology" (in Japanese) by Kazuo Matsuzaka.

> Let $(S,\mathcal{O})$ be a topological space.
> Let $x\in S$.
> If $V$ is a subset of $S$ such that $x\in\operatorname{Int} V$, then $V$ is called a neighborhood of $x$.
> Let $\mathbf{V}_S(x)$ be the set of all neighborhoods of $x$.
> $\mathbf{V}_S(x)$ is called a neighborhood system of $x$.
> If $\mathbf{V}^{*}_S(x)$ is a subset of $\mathbf{V}_S(x)$ such that if $V\in\mathbf{V}_S(x)$, there exists $U\in\mathbf{V}_S^{*}(x)$ such that $U\subset V$, then $\mathbf{V}_S^{*}(x)$ is called a neighborhood basis for $x$.

The author wrote the following corollary of a theorem:

> Corollary 2 on p.192:
> Let $S_\lambda$ be a topological space for each $\lambda\in\Lambda$.
> Let $x=(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ be a point of $S=\Pi_{\lambda\in\Lambda} S_\lambda$.
> Then, $$\{(\Pi_{\lambda\in\Lambda-\{\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\}} S_\lambda)\times V_{\lambda_1}\times\dots\times V_{\lambda_n}\mid\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\text{ are distinct elements of }\Lambda, V_{\lambda_i}\in\mathbf{V}_{S_{\lambda_i}}(x_{\lambda_i}) \}$$ is a neighborhood basis for $x$.

The author wrote $V_{\lambda_i}\in\mathbf{V}_{S_{\lambda_i}}(x_{\lambda_i})$.
But I think it is better to write $V_{\lambda_i}\in\mathbf{V}_{S_{\lambda_i}}^{*}(x_{\lambda_i})$ because $\mathbf{V}_{S_{\lambda_i}}(x_{\lambda_i})$ is also a neighborhood basis for $x$.
My Corollary 2 is the following:

> My Corollary 2:
> Let $S_\lambda$ be a topological space for each $\lambda\in\Lambda$.
> Let $x=(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ be a point of $S=\Pi_{\lambda\in\Lambda} S_\lambda$.
> Then, $$\{(\Pi_{\lambda\in\Lambda-\{\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\}} S_\lambda)\times V_{\lambda_1}\times\dots\times V_{\lambda_n}\mid\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\text{ are distinct elements of }\Lambda, V_{\lambda_i}\in\mathbf{V}_{S_{\lambda_i}}^{*}(x_{\lambda_i})\}$$ is a neighborhood basis for $x$.

The author wrote Corollary 2 and the author didn't write my Corollary 2.
Why?
I suspect this is an erratum.

Comment: Your corollary is indeed correct and  better.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you very much for your answer.